# How to create custom theme for XFCE?

Tags: xfce, theme, window-decorations

I'm trying to create a custom theme to modify windows decorations colors.

I copied the folder of the theme that I want to modify (Smallscreen) from `/usr/share/themes/` and pasted it to `~/.themes`. I changed the name to avoid duplicate.

After that, I changed some `.xpm` files to make it look like I want.

When I open the Window Manager to set my new theme, it appears in the list, but when I choose it, it looks like the original one without my modifications. I tried to change to a completely different theme and change to my new theme after to make sure the change is taken into account. I checked all the text files in the theme and couldn't find a pointer to the original folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have this: https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes , in regards to paths etc? Do not have XFCE installed so can not test, but it sounds like a path issue ...

Comment: I already tried this, but it sill uses the wrong theme.

Comment: Anything in `dmesg` after applying?

Comment: No, nothing....

Comment: I set up a renamed copy of "Smallscreen" in `~/.themes` as you did, used the GIMP to change the colors of `close-inactive.xpm` to a white 'x' on red background, changed themes in the Window Manager, and it worked. What `.xpm` file(s) are you changing and, in case it makes a difference, what style do you have set in the Appearance settings?